# Static files are still being served from file system instead of AWS-S3 in Flask

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, flask

I have a script that generates an image.
That image is saved in a directory inside my OS static folder. image.png is saved in:

```
-static
    -images
        -monkeys
            - image.png
```

The server endpoint function should upload the image into my S3-bucket and return that static file from my bucket, not from my OS file system.

This does not work for some reason.
The image uploading works fine, I can see the image in the bucket, I'm just not able to serve the static image, I get an error: 
"The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.". Basically it cannot find the image.

I am using flask-S3 in the following way:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['FLASKS3_BUCKET_NAME'] = os.environ.get('S3_BUCKET_NAMEING')
app.config['USE_S3_DEBUG'] = True
s3 = FlaskS3(app)
```

My endpoint for serving the static image:

```
@app.route('/image/monkey/<address>', methods = ['GET'])
def monkey_image(address):
        # There is some code here that generates that image and places it 
        # inside the monkeys folder. I did not include it because
        # it is not relevant to the question 
        image = open(image_path, 'rb')
        S3_path = 'images/monkeysS3/' + monkey_image_name
        upload_image_to_s3_bucket(image,'static/' + S3_path)
        return redirect(flask_url_for('static', filename=S3_path))
```

So the last 2 lines matters.

> upload_image_to_s3 works. The issue comes from

```
return redirect(flask_url_for('static', filename=path)).
```

It just can't find the image inside my S3 bucket.
This goes for development and production as well.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `flask_url_for` returns correct url?

Comment: You should use `flask_s3.url_for` ([documentation](https://flask-s3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_s3.url_for)).